# How can I install MP4Box on CentOS7.3

Tags: centos, mp4box

I can't install MP4Box on CentOS7.3.
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

I attempted to install with reference to the following URL.
https://www.24x7serversolutions.com/blog/install-mp4box-on-centos/

```
yum -y install freetype-devel SDL-devel freeglut-devel
wget http://repo.bstack.net/mp4box/gpac-0.4.5.tar.gz
wget http://repo.bstack.net/mp4box/gpac_extra_libs-0.4.5.tar.gz
tar -zxvf gpac-0.4.5.tar.gz
tar -zxvf gpac_extra_libs-0.4.5.tar.gz
cd gpac_extra_libs
cp -r * /usr/local/src/gpac/extra_lib
cd ..
cd gpac
chmod 755 configure
./configure
```

But, at the time of this command,

```
make lib
・・・
gcc: エラー: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wl’
gcc: エラー: unrecognized command line option ‘--warn-common’
make[1]: *** [libgpac.so] エラー 1
make[1]: ディレクトリ `/home/source/gpac/src' から出ます
make: *** [lib] エラー 2
```

I tried to set ln as following.

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/libglut.so.3 /usr/lib64/libglut.so
```

But, the same error was displayed.

How do I deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need MP4Box only from GPAC, I recommend that you follow [this tutorial](http://gpac.io/2015/07/29/gpac-build-mp4box-only-all-platforms/).

You need the following packages: git, gcc, make, libpthread-devel.

Execute these command-lines:

```
git clone https://github.com/gpac/gpac.git
cd gpac
./configure --static-mp4box --use-zlib=no
make -j4
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I installed the latest version of MP4Box from the GitHub. The main purpose of this script is to install the MP4Box to docker centos amazoncorretto container.

```
yum -y install freetype-devel SDL-devel freeglut-devel ugcc gcc-c++ git libtool make zlib-devel

git clone https://github.com/gpac/gpac gpac_public
cd gpac_public
./configure --static-mp4box
make
make install
```

This is the combination of two resources:

https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/GPAC-Build-Guide-for-Linux
https://gist.github.com/helpsquad/48ee2baf2eb5ee655e8755618b4c8c75

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a bug in that version of `gpac`. Try this instead:

```
yum -y install freetype-devel SDL-devel freeglut-devel

git clone https://github.com/gpac/gpac
cd gpac
git checkout tags/v0.6.1 -b v0.6.1

./configure
make lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's there on the official "rpmfusion-free" repository.

Just do:

sudo yum install gpac

(Taken from: http://rahul-ghose.blogspot.com/2017/05/install-mp4-box-on-centos.html)

Answer (score -1):

Mp4Box included in [gpac](https://github.com/gpac/gpac), so you must install gpac.

```
yum install gpac
```